# Seaborn catplot sort by columns

Tags: pandas, sorting, seaborn, catplot

I am trying to sort the columns in seaborn catplot and I am unable to perform this operation. I know I can sort the bars within the graph using `order=` but how to sort the columns?
So far, I have written this code for plotting:

```
top_codes = df["Code"].value_counts()[:5].index.tolist()
top_stations = df["Station"].value_counts()[:5].index.tolist()
sns.catplot(x='Code',col='Station', data=df.loc[(df['Code'].isin(top_codes)) & (df['Station'].isin(top_stations))],
            kind='count', col_wrap=5)
```

The above code produces the following result:
[image]

I want station names, e.g., KENNEDY BD STATION, SHEPPHARD WEST STATION, FINCH STATION to appear in  alphabetical order.

Comment: Perhaps change `df.loc[(df['Code'].isin(top_codes)) & (df['Station'].isin(top_stations))` to `df.loc[(df['Code'].isin(top_codes)) & (df['Station'].isin(top_stations)).sort_values(by="Station")` in the plot code.

Comment: `df.Station = pd.Categorical(df.Station, sorted(df.Station.unique()), ordered=True)` [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4p0S.png)

Answer (score 0):

A simple ascending sort is very easy: just call the `sorted()` function.
Add `code_order=sorted(top_stations)` as parameter to `sns.catplot` like this:

```
top_codes = df["Code"].value_counts()[:5].index.tolist()
top_stations = df["Station"].value_counts()[:5].index.tolist()
sns.catplot(x='Code',col='Station', data=df.loc[(df['Code'].isin(top_codes)) & (df['Station'].isin(top_stations))],
        kind='count', col_wrap=5, code_order=sorted(top_stations))
```